# Jquery Not This

Tags: jquery, html

How do I hide all other items in a category that are not "this?"  Basically am trying to do a simple sort.

When you click on one category, show it and hide all the others.

```
<nav> 
     <a href="#">Student</a> 
     <a href="parent" class="parentbtn">Parent</a>
</nav>
<div class="category student"> Student Form </div>
<div class="category student"> Student Form </div>
<div class="category student"> Student Form </div>
<div class="category student"> Student Form </div>
<div class="category student"> Student Form </div>

<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>
<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>
<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>
<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>
<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>
<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>

$( ".parentbtn" ).click(function() {
  $( ".parent" ).not(this).slideUp("slow");

});
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYWpBE

Comment: `this` will refer to the `.parentbtn`.  It's *not* a `.parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made a quick pen with some changes. just switch hide/show to slide.

Now it takes the href in the link, saves it as the name of the filter. On click it hides all divs that not has that class. so if you click "students" it will show all divs that has that class and hide all others.

codepen.io/anon/pen/LEYyPo

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
  var filter = this.href;
  $('div').hide();
  $('.'+filter ).show();
});
```

EDIT: new pen.

Comment: eventually I'd have many categories, so am trying to stay away from hardcoding each class in there.

Comment: ah, i see. sorry then.

Comment: @user2952238: Add the code from the link *into* the answer.  Just in case the link goes down.

Comment: @Deedub made a new pen. etited my post.

Comment: BOOM, that's it.... do you mind telling me the logic of it? I think I get it but just to make sure :)

Comment: @Deedub kind of a quick fix to use the attr href. better practice to use a data-attribute if you're gonna have a lot of filters to handle.

Comment: @Deedub sure thing. added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
$('nav a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cls = $(this).data()['cat'];
    $('.category').show().not(cls).slideUp('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav> 
     <a href="#" data-cat=".student">Student</a> 
     <a href="#" data-cat=".parent" class="parentbtn">Parent</a>
</nav>
<div class="category student"> Student Form </div>
<div class="category student"> Student Form </div>
<div class="category student"> Student Form </div>
<div class="category student"> Student Form </div>
<div class="category student"> Student Form </div>

<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>
<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>
<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>
<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>
<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>
<div class="category parent"> Parent Form </div>
```

Comment: Why are you doing `$(this).data()['cat']`?  Why not `$(this).data('cat')`?